# OpenGl : Rotate line about endpoint

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL , and trying out some experimental code. I'm using Open GL 4+ . I was able to draw a line using this :

```
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glEnd();
```

Now I want to rotate this line about one of it's endpoints, like the hand of a clock. How do I go about doing this? I've searched online, but there's nothing that actually demonstrates simple line rotation. I tried using `glRotatef` but I think I'm missing out on some key thing, because the `glRotatef` had no effect on the line drawn. All tutorials seem to start with Triangles (not points and lines)

What is the OpenGL workflow for doing these things? I keep coming across sample code where matrices are being used, but I don't exactly get the purpose.. I mean, do I have to explicitly keep track of my latest matrices, or is abstracted away by OpenGL and internally taken care of?

I understand the math and the role of transformation matrices, but I'm getting confused about the matrices' role in writing OpenGL code. If there are functions like `glRotatef` , why explicitly specify matrices?

It'd be really helpful to have some resources that explain everything from the very basic - points, lines *then* polygons etc

Comment: If you're using `glBegin`, you're not using OpenGL 4. Please try to learn the newer API.

Comment: I'm using `glBegin` from the tutorial I came across. My system has both the libraries, so this code was able to compile.

Comment: You can use `glBegin` because you're using a *compatibility* OpenGL context, but it's not a modern OpenGL API.

Comment: Yes, I got that. This is just some trial code, but I do eventually have to use the new API only.. But the question is more about the general workflow for transformations..

Comment: A good start is for example to use the GLM (OpenGL Mathematics) library so you can work with your own matrices, points and vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

standard disclaimer: don't use glBegine/glEnd family of functions instead migrate to the shader based setup.

but here is the way to rotate (left out the parameters)

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslate();//tranlate by -p where p is the point you want to rotate about
glRotate();//rotate by some degrees
glTranslate();//tranlate back by p

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Thanks.. How do I do the same with the shader based setup? Can you point me to some good resources for the new API?

Comment: [their wiki has a good setup](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page) to do this in a shader based setup you will need to maintain your own matrices and multiply the vertexes by it in the vertex shader