# OpenGL: What does glRotatef rotate?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-1.x

When I call the `glRotatef` like this:

```
glRotatef(angle,0.0,1.0,0.0) //rotate about y-axis
```

I know it is to rotate by `angle` degrees about the `y axis`.
But, *what* is being rotated here? Which object exactly?

Probably a silly question, but I'm entirely new to this.

I was able to rotate a line about it's endpoint using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289143/opengl-rotate-line-about-endpoint) , but I don't really understand how it works internally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is being rotated, because OpenGL does not "store" objects.

glRotatef, like glMultMatrixf, is used to modify the currently selected transformation matrix. This has an effect on how things are drawn subsequently. One sets the matrices (and other stuff!) how one wants, and then one draws one's objects.

For more information, see the OpenGL redbook, and google around for the difference between "retained mode" and "immediate mode".

Comment: Not only does OpenGL not _store_ objects, it literally has no notion of the _concept_ of objects.

Comment: @sanjeevmk The transformation matrix is applied to the vertices you pass in using `glVertex`.

Answer (score 2):

`glRotate` will act on the current matrix, which is by default `GL_MODELVIEW`. Doing so will affect any 3D object that you draw in the sequence. The current matrix is changed with [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml).
The model-view matrix is then applied to any geometry rendered with `glVertex`, `glDrawArrays`, etc.

OpenGL-side matrices are now deprecated. If you use core OpenGL 3+, these functions are no longer available. If you are new to OpenGL, I suggest that you skip learning the old ways and focus on modern, shader-oriented OpenGL. You can check the following links for some good tutorials.

1. [open.gl](http://open.gl/)
2. [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/)
3. [ogldev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/)